# C#: How to show "Open with" dialogue-box for a file?

Tags: c#, .net

How to open a file from C# showing "Open with" dialogue-box?

> **Open with dialogue box**: A dialogue box that shows up when we
>   right-click on file + click on "open with" + Click on "Choose
>   program".